# Source for ccnet-dbg and libccnet-dbg

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, lubuntu, dependencies, debug

I am trying to install SeaFile server on Lubuntu 20.04.3.
So that I can report any errors, I ran the command in the documentation and tried to install ccnet-dbg and libccnet-dbg.
I got the error "Unable to locate package" for each of these. Seems I don't have the software source listed for these.
Can someone tell me the source to enable, please, as several online searches have not provided that information.
Thanks.

Comment: Were you following this guide: https://help.seafile.com/syncing_client/install_linux_client/ ?

Comment: The package `libccnet-dbg` is not available for any release of Ubuntu - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libccnet-dbg&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all`   Providing the instructions you're following, as Lubuntu/Ubuntu documentation makes no mention of it  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libdevel/libccnet-dev maybe closest; but I'd want to know what instructions you're following; that was removed as it relied on python2 which is EOL)

Comment: See also https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ccnet

Comment: @Liso, yes, that was the documentation I was following -- incorrectly as it turns out, because that is for installing a SeaFile client, but I'm trying to install the server side. Silly me :-(

Comment: @guiverc, thanks for that information. I guess the SeaFile documentation needs to be updated.

Comment: @guiverc, would you like to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I *think* you might need a new software if SeaFile server depends on something that has been superseded upstream since 2018.  Sounds like you're trying to use legacy, nonexistent software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package libccnet-dbg is not available for any release of Ubuntu - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libccnet-dbg&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Providing the instructions you're following, as Lubuntu/Ubuntu documentation makes no mention of it.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libdevel/libccnet-dev maybe closest; but I'd want to know what instructions you're following; that was removed as it relied on python2 which is EOL for a start.

Another significant problem was that the upstream repository was deleted; refer https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ccnet